# Failure to run a jmh test under java9

Tags: java, java-9, jmh

So basically I am trying to run a test in the form of:

```
@Benchmark
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = "-Djava.lang.invoke.stringConcat=java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.Strategy.BC_SB", value = 1)
public String java9StringBuilder(ThreadState state) {
    // some implementation here
}
```

Running it with:

```
java -jar benchmarks.jar MyFullClassNameHere -v extra
```

Unfortunately it fails with `forked VM failed with exit code 1` and no more "verbose" output.

What I am doing wrong?

I do get these warnings:

> WARNING: Unknown module: org.openjdk specified to --add-exports
>
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.openjdk.jmh.util.Utils (file:/Path/Here/benchmarks.jar) to field java.io.Console.cs
>
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.openjdk.jmh.util.Utils
>
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: Could you add to how did you build the `benchmarks.jar` and other steps involved(if)? Building with javac 1.8 and executing the jar with java9 works fine for me.

Comment: @nullpointer if u look at the parameter its only available in 9; building it is as simple as `mnv clean install`

Comment: correct, but the jar could be built with Java8 as well as the value of the annotated arg is simply a string. Of course no doubts, the execution is only possible with Java9. That's what I stated for as and when I tried to reproduce.

Comment: @nullpointer if u are compiling against 8, there will be no `invokedynamic` for string concatation... I wonder if that parameter is ignored when running on 9

Comment: I think I could [reproduce this](https://github.com/namannigam/jdk9-jmh-jvmargs). Could you verify the error log in the README is similar to yours?

Comment: @nullpointer it is, notice how that is actually a `warning`... will post to jmh-dev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with Java 9 in this example. You are supplying JVM options to the forked VM, have you tried running with that option without JMH first? Then you would notice the command is incorrect, and the correct form is:

```
- @Fork(jvmArgs = "-Djava.lang.invoke.stringConcat=java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.Strategy.BC_SB")
+ @Fork(jvmArgs = "-Djava.lang.invoke.stringConcat=BC_SB")
```

...because `BC_SB` is the enum constant in `java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.Strategy` enum.

Comment: Also what is incorrect with `jvmArgsAppend`? Just curious

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `jvmArgsAppend`. If you blew the `stringConcat` option, forked VM fails without anything useful can be printed out. When in doubt, why don't you supply the option to the ad-hoc JVM invocation, and see if it works?

Comment: I actually did, but I guess the `-Djava.lang.invoke.stringConcat=java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.Strategy.BC_SB` gets ignored and wouldn't be noticed either during the normal execution as well.